# Using subquerys in Update statement

Tags: sql-server, subquery, sql-update

I have the following SQL statement in a trigger that fires on deletion:

```
UPDATE bk2_InfoPages
SET SortOrder = SortOrder - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Deleted d WHERE d.SortOrder <= SortOrder)
```

My problem is that the very last `SortOrder` refers to the `Deleted` table and not to the `bk2_InfoPages` table. I am not allowed to add an alias to the `bk2_InfoPages` table because it's an `UPDATE` statement - so what should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE b
SET SortOrder = SortOrder - 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Deleted d WHERE d.SortOrder <= b.SortOrder)
from bk2_InfoPages b
```

You have to alias your table to do sub queries, for example:

```
-- this executes fine 
create table #t ( t int)

update t 
set t = (select count(*) from #t t1 where t.t = t1.t)
from #t t
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE bk2_InfoPages
SET SortOrder = SortOrder - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Deleted d WHERE d.SortOrder <= bk2_InfoPages.SortOrder)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got the following error message when trying to execute the ALTER TRIGGER statement: "The multi-part identifier "bk2_InfoPages.SortOrder" could not be bound."

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would work!

```
UPDATE bk2_InfoPages
SET SortOrder = SortOrder - subquery.c
FROM (
SELECT SortOrder, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM Deleted d
GROUP BY SortOrder
) AS subquery
WHERE subquery.SortOrder <= bk2_InfoPages.SortOrder;
```